# Implementação do Shodan(Api) Não retorna resultado

Tags: python, api, iot

Boa tarde.
Então pessoal to fazendo um teste com o shodan para implementar em um outro programa.
Porem quando eu digito  $:python python_test.py.py + ip ou query
Ele não exibe o resultado e rtorna para o terminal sem erro tambem.
Como posso concertar isso?
Ps: Eu uso minha api.
Qual é o problema?
PS2: O nome do arquivo não é shodan para evitar o bug de collision.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import shodan

api = shodan.Shodan("MyAPI")

results = api.search('apache')

def Shodan(self):

def check_params(self):

self.get_api_key("MyAPI")

    def get_accepted_types(self):
        return [IP]

    def get_api_key(self):
        key = Config.plugin_args.get("apikey", None)
        if not key:
            key = Config.plugin_config.get("apikey", None)
        if not key:
            raise ValueError(
                "Missing API key! Get one at:"
                " http://www.shodanhq.com/api_doc")
        return key

    def run(self, info):

        # This is where we'll collect the data we'll return.
        results = []

        # Skip unsupported IP addresses.
        if info.version != 4:
            return
        ip = info.address
        parsed = netaddr.IPAddress(ip)
        if parsed.is_loopback() or \
           parsed.is_private()  or \
           parsed.is_link_local():
            return

        # Query Shodan for this host.
        try:
            key = self.get_api_key()
            api = WebAPI(key)
            shodan = api.host(ip)
        except Exception, e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            Logger.log_error("Error querying Shodan: %s" % str(e))
            Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
            return

        # Make sure we got the same IP address we asked for.
        if ip != shodan.get("ip", ip):
            Logger.log_error(
                "Shodan gave us a different IP address... weird!")
            Logger.log_error_verbose(
                "Old IP: %s - New IP: %s" % (ip, shodan["ip"]))
            ip = to_utf8( shodan["ip"] )
            info = IP(ip)
            results.append(info)

        # Extract all hostnames and link them to this IP address.
        # Note: sometimes Shodan sends IP addresses here! (?)
        seen_host = {}
        for hostname in shodan.get("hostnames", []):
            if hostname == ip:
                continue
            if hostname in seen_host:
                domain = seen_host[hostname]
            else:
                try:
                    try:
                        host = IP(hostname)
                    except ValueError:
                        host = Domain(hostname)
                except Exception:
                    tb = traceback.format_exc()
                    Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                seen_host[hostname] = host
                results.append(host)
                domain = host
            domain.add_resource(info)

        # Get the OS fingerprint, if available.
        os = to_utf8( shodan.get("os") )
        if os:
            Logger.log("Host %s is running %s" % (ip, os))
            pass  # XXX TODO we'll need to reverse lookup the CPE

        # Get the GPS data, if available.
        # Complete any missing data using the default values.
        try:
            latitude  = float( shodan["latitude"]  )
            longitude = float( shodan["longitude"] )
        except Exception:
            latitude  = None
            longitude = None
        if latitude is not None and longitude is not None:
            area_code = shodan.get("area_code")
            if not area_code:
                area_code = None
            country_code = shodan.get("country_code")
            if not country_code:
                country_code = shodan.get("country_code3")
                if not country_code:
                    country_code = None
            country_name = shodan.get("country_name")
            if not country_name:
                country_name = None
            city = shodan.get("city")
            if not city:
                city = None
            dma_code = shodan.get("dma_code")
            if not dma_code:
                dma_code = None
            postal_code = shodan.get("postal_code")
            if not postal_code:
                postal_code = None
            region_name = shodan.get("region_name")
            if not region_name:
                region_name = None
            geoip = Geolocation(
                latitude, longitude,
                country_code = country_code,
                country_name = country_name,
                region_name = region_name,
                city = city,
                zipcode = postal_code,
                metro_code = dma_code,
                areacode = area_code,
            )
            results.append(geoip)
            geoip.add_resource(info)

        # Go through every result and pick only the latest ones.
        latest = {}
        for data in shodan.get("data", []):
            if (
                not "banner" in data or
                not "ip" in data or
                not "port" in data or
                not "timestamp" in data
            ):
                Logger.log_error("Malformed results from Shodan?")
                from pprint import pformat
                Logger.log_error_more_verbose(pformat(data))
                continue
            key = (
                data["ip"],
                data["port"],
                data["banner"],
            )
            try:
                timestamp = reversed(   # DD.MM.YYYY -> (YYYY, MM, DD)
                    map(int, data["timestamp"].split(".", 2)))
            except Exception:
                continue
            if key not in latest or timestamp > latest[key][0]:
                latest[key] = (timestamp, data)

        # Process the latest results.
        seen_isp_or_org = set()
        seen_html = set()
        for _, data in latest.values():

            # Extract all domains, but don't link them.
            for hostname in data.get("domains", []):
                if hostname not in seen_host:
                    try:
                        domain = Domain(hostname)
                    except Exception:
                        tb = traceback.format_exc()
                        Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                        continue
                    seen_host[hostname] = domain
                    results.append(domain)

            # We don't have any use for this information yet,
            # but log it so at least the user can see it.
            isp = to_utf8( data.get("isp") )
            org = to_utf8( data.get("org") )
            if org and org not in seen_isp_or_org:
                seen_isp_or_org.add(org)
                Logger.log_verbose(
                    "Host %s belongs to: %s"
                    % (ip, org)
                )
            if isp and (not org or isp != org) and isp not in seen_isp_or_org:
                seen_isp_or_org.add(isp)
                Logger.log_verbose(
                    "IP address %s is provided by ISP: %s"
                    % (ip, isp)
                )

            # Get the HTML content, if available.
            raw_html = to_utf8( data.get("html") )
            if raw_html:
                hash_raw_html = hash(raw_html)
                if hash_raw_html not in seen_html:
                    seen_html.add(hash_raw_html)
                    try:
                        html = HTML(raw_html)
                    except Exception:
                        html = None
                        tb = traceback.format_exc()
                        Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                    if html:
                        html.add_resource(info)
                        results.append(html)

            # Get the banner, if available.
            raw_banner = to_utf8( data.get("banner") )
            try:
                port = int( data.get("port", "0") )
            except Exception:
                port = 0
            if raw_banner and port:
                try:
                    banner = Banner(info, raw_banner, port)
                except Exception:
                    banner = None
                    tb = traceback.format_exc()
                    Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                if banner:
                    results.append(banner)

        # Was this host located somewhere else in the past?
        for data in reversed(shodan.get("data", [])):
            try:
                timestamp = reversed(   # DD.MM.YYYY -> (YYYY, MM, DD)
                    map(int, data["timestamp"].split(".", 2)))
                old_location = data.get("location")
                if old_location:
                    old_latitude  = old_location.get("latitude",  latitude)
                    old_longitude = old_location.get("longitude", longitude)
                    if (
                        old_latitude is not None and
                        old_longitude is not None and
                        (old_latitude != latitude or old_longitude != longitude)
                    ):

                        # Get the geoip information.
                        area_code = old_location.get("area_code")
                        if not area_code:
                            area_code = None
                        country_code = old_location.get("country_code")
                        if not country_code:
                            country_code = old_location.get("country_code3")
                            if not country_code:
                                country_code = None
                        country_name = old_location.get("country_name")
                        if not country_name:
                            country_name = None
                        city = old_location.get("city")
                        if not city:
                            city = None
                        postal_code = old_location.get("postal_code")
                        if not postal_code:
                            postal_code = None
                        region_name = old_location.get("region_name")
                        if not region_name:
                            region_name = None
                        geoip = Geolocation(
                            latitude, longitude,
                            country_code = country_code,
                            country_name = country_name,
                            region_name = region_name,
                            city = city,
                            zipcode = postal_code,
                            areacode = area_code,
                        )

                        # If this is the first time we geolocate this IP,
                        # use this information as it if were up to date.
                        if latitude is None or longitude is None:
                            latitude  = old_latitude
                            longitude = old_longitude
                            results.append(geoip)
                            geoip.add_resource(info)

                        # Otherwise, just log the event.
                        else:
                            discard_data(geoip)
                            where = str(geoip)
                            when = datetime.date(*timestamp)
                            msg = "Host %s used to be located at %s on %s."
                            msg %= (ip, where, when.strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
                            Logger.log_verbose(msg)

            except Exception:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)

        # Return the results.
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns updates no code e ainda não exibe o resultado;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import shodan
api = shodan.Shodan("MyApi")
results = api.search('https://api.shodan.io')


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def Shodan(self):

    """
    This plugin tries to perform passive reconnaissance on a target using
    the Shodan web API.
    """


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def check_params(self):

        # Make sure we have an API key.
        self.get_api_key("MyAPI")


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def get_accepted_types(self):
        return [IP]
 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def get_api_key(self):
        key = Config.plugin_args.get("apikey", None)
        if not key:
            key = Config.plugin_config.get("apikey", None)
        if not key:
            raise ValueError(
                "Missing API key! Get one at:"
                " http://www.shodanhq.com/api_doc")
        return key


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def run(self, info):

        # This is where we'll collect the data we'll return.
        results = []

        # Skip unsupported IP addresses.
        if info.version != 4:
            return
        ip = info.address
        parsed = netaddr.IPAddress(ip)
        if parsed.is_loopback() or \
           parsed.is_private()  or \
           parsed.is_link_local():
            return

        # Query Shodan for this host.
        try:
            key = self.get_api_key()
            api = WebAPI(key)
            shodan = api.host(ip)
        except Exception, e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            Logger.log_error("Error querying Shodan: %s" % str(e))
            Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
            return

        # Make sure we got the same IP address we asked for.
        if ip != shodan.get("ip", ip):
            Logger.log_error(
                "Shodan gave us a different IP address... weird!")
            Logger.log_error_verbose(
                "Old IP: %s - New IP: %s" % (ip, shodan["ip"]))
            ip = to_utf8( shodan["ip"] )
            info = IP(ip)
            results.append(info)

        # Extract all hostnames and link them to this IP address.
        # Note: sometimes Shodan sends IP addresses here! (?)
        seen_host = {}
        for hostname in shodan.get("hostnames", []):
            if hostname == ip:
                continue
            if hostname in seen_host:
                domain = seen_host[hostname]
            else:
                try:
                    try:
                        host = IP(hostname)
                    except ValueError:
                        host = Domain(hostname)
                except Exception:
                    tb = traceback.format_exc()
                    Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                seen_host[hostname] = host
                results.append(host)
                domain = host
            domain.add_resource(info)

        # Get the OS fingerprint, if available.
        os = to_utf8( shodan.get("os") )
        if os:
            Logger.log("Host %s is running %s" % (ip, os))
            pass  # XXX TODO we'll need to reverse lookup the CPE

        # Get the GPS data, if available.
        # Complete any missing data using the default values.
        try:
            latitude  = float( shodan["latitude"]  )
            longitude = float( shodan["longitude"] )
        except Exception:
            latitude  = None
            longitude = None
        if latitude is not None and longitude is not None:
            area_code = shodan.get("area_code")
            if not area_code:
                area_code = None
            country_code = shodan.get("country_code")
            if not country_code:
                country_code = shodan.get("country_code3")
                if not country_code:
                    country_code = None
            country_name = shodan.get("country_name")
            if not country_name:
                country_name = None
            city = shodan.get("city")
            if not city:
                city = None
            dma_code = shodan.get("dma_code")
            if not dma_code:
                dma_code = None
            postal_code = shodan.get("postal_code")
            if not postal_code:
                postal_code = None
            region_name = shodan.get("region_name")
            if not region_name:
                region_name = None
            geoip = Geolocation(
                latitude, longitude,
                country_code = country_code,
                country_name = country_name,
                region_name = region_name,
                city = city,
                zipcode = postal_code,
                metro_code = dma_code,
                areacode = area_code,
            )
            results.append(geoip)
            geoip.add_resource(info)

        # Go through every result and pick only the latest ones.
        latest = {}
        for data in shodan.get("data", []):
            if (
                not "banner" in data or
                not "ip" in data or
                not "port" in data or
                not "timestamp" in data
            ):
                Logger.log_error("Malformed results from Shodan?")
                from pprint import pformat
                Logger.log_error_more_verbose(pformat(data))
                continue
            key = (
                data["ip"],
                data["port"],
                data["banner"],
            )
            try:
                timestamp = reversed(   # DD.MM.YYYY -> (YYYY, MM, DD)
                    map(int, data["timestamp"].split(".", 2)))
            except Exception:
                continue
            if key not in latest or timestamp > latest[key][0]:
                latest[key] = (timestamp, data)

        # Process the latest results.
        seen_isp_or_org = set()
        seen_html = set()
        for _, data in latest.values():

            # Extract all domains, but don't link them.
            for hostname in data.get("domains", []):
                if hostname not in seen_host:
                    try:
                        domain = Domain(hostname)
                    except Exception:
                        tb = traceback.format_exc()
                        Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                        continue
                    seen_host[hostname] = domain
                    results.append(domain)

            # We don't have any use for this information yet,
            # but log it so at least the user can see it.
            isp = to_utf8( data.get("isp") )
            org = to_utf8( data.get("org") )
            if org and org not in seen_isp_or_org:
                seen_isp_or_org.add(org)
                Logger.log_verbose(
                    "Host %s belongs to: %s"
                    % (ip, org)
                )
            if isp and (not org or isp != org) and isp not in seen_isp_or_org:
                seen_isp_or_org.add(isp)
                Logger.log_verbose(
                    "IP address %s is provided by ISP: %s"
                    % (ip, isp)
                )

            # Get the HTML content, if available.
            raw_html = to_utf8( data.get("html") )
            if raw_html:
                hash_raw_html = hash(raw_html)
                if hash_raw_html not in seen_html:
                    seen_html.add(hash_raw_html)
                    try:
                        html = HTML(raw_html)
                    except Exception:
                        html = None
                        tb = traceback.format_exc()
                        Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                    if html:
                        html.add_resource(info)
                        results.append(html)

            # Get the banner, if available.
            raw_banner = to_utf8( data.get("banner") )
            try:
                port = int( data.get("port", "0") )
            except Exception:
                port = 0
            if raw_banner and port:
                try:
                    banner = Banner(info, raw_banner, port)
                except Exception:
                    banner = None
                    tb = traceback.format_exc()
                    Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)
                if banner:
                    results.append(banner)

        # Was this host located somewhere else in the past?
        for data in reversed(shodan.get("data", [])):
            try:
                timestamp = reversed(   # DD.MM.YYYY -> (YYYY, MM, DD)
                    map(int, data["timestamp"].split(".", 2)))
                old_location = data.get("location")
                if old_location:
                    old_latitude  = old_location.get("latitude",  latitude)
                    old_longitude = old_location.get("longitude", longitude)
                    if (
                        old_latitude is not None and
                        old_longitude is not None and
                        (old_latitude != latitude or old_longitude != longitude)
                    ):

                        # Get the geoip information.
                        area_code = old_location.get("area_code")
                        if not area_code:
                            area_code = None
                        country_code = old_location.get("country_code")
                        if not country_code:
                            country_code = old_location.get("country_code3")
                            if not country_code:
                                country_code = None
                        country_name = old_location.get("country_name")
                        if not country_name:
                            country_name = None
                        city = old_location.get("city")
                        if not city:
                            city = None
                        postal_code = old_location.get("postal_code")
                        if not postal_code:
                            postal_code = None
                        region_name = old_location.get("region_name")
                        if not region_name:
                            region_name = None
                        geoip = Geolocation(
                            latitude, longitude,
                            country_code = country_code,
                            country_name = country_name,
                            region_name = region_name,
                            city = city,
                            zipcode = postal_code,
                            areacode = area_code,
                        )

                        # If this is the first time we geolocate this IP,
                        # use this information as it if were up to date.
                        if latitude is None or longitude is None:
                            latitude  = old_latitude
                            longitude = old_longitude
                            results.append(geoip)
                            geoip.add_resource(info)

                        # Otherwise, just log the event.
                        else:
                            discard_data(geoip)
                            where = str(geoip)
                            when = datetime.date(*timestamp)
                            msg = "Host %s used to be located at %s on %s."
                            msg %= (ip, where, when.strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
                            Logger.log_verbose(msg)

            except Exception:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                Logger.log_error_more_verbose(tb)

        # Return the results.
        return results
```